# C# Timer-controlled for loop iteration not working

Tags: loops, for-loop, timer

I'm working on a C# WinForms app that uses a System.Timers.Timer to pause the thread between repetitions in a for loop. It's a slideshow app that uses Transitions.dll to bring the images onto the screen.

Here's the global declaration of the timer:

```
    public System.Timers.Timer tmrPause = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

Here's the for loop:

```
    private void SlideShow()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstChosenTBImages.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == glbintChosenTBIndex)
                glbblIsCorrectImage = true;

            if (i == 1 || i == 11)
                TransFromLeft(i);
            else if (i == 2 || i == 12)
                TransFromRight(i);
            else if (i == 0 || i == 3)
                TransFromTop(i);
            else if (i == 4)
                TransFromBottom(i);
            else if (i == 5 || i == 10)
                TransFromBack(i);
            else if (i == 6)
                TransFromUpperLeft(i);
            else if (i == 7)
                TransFromUpperRight(i);
            else if (i == 8)
                TransFromLowerLeft(i);
            else if (i == 9)
                TransFromLowerRight(i);
        }
    }
```

Here's the TransFromLeft method (all other transition methods listed in the above for loop are the same):

```
    private void TransFromLeft(int intImage)
    {
        Point ptPicBoxLoc = glbptpbImageLoc;

        PictureBox pbTBImage = new PictureBox();
        pbTBImage.Parent = this; 
        pbTBImage.Size = new Size(196, 200);
        pbTBImage.BackColor = Color.Black;
        pbTBImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pbTBImage.Image = lstChosenTBImages[intImage].imgTBImage;

        Transition tFromLeft = new Transition(new TransitionType_Acceleration(750));
        pbTBImage.Location = new Point(-1200, pbTBImage.Location.Y);
        tFromLeft.add(pbTBImage, "Left", ptPicBoxLoc.X);
        tFromLeft.add(pbTBImage, "Top", ptPicBoxLoc.Y);
        pbTBImage.Visible = true;
        pbTBImage.Refresh();
        tFromLeft.TransitionCompletedEvent += tFromLeft_TransitionCompletedEvent;
        tFromLeft.run();
    }
```

Here's the transition completed event handler for the TransFromLeft method:

```
    private void tFromLeft_TransitionCompletedEvent(object sender, Transitions.Transition.Args e)
    {
        StartTheTimer();
    }
```

Here's the StartTheTimer method:

```
    private void StartTheTimer()
    {
        tmrPause.Enabled = true;
        tmrPause.Interval = 2000;
        tmrPause.Elapsed += tmrPause_Elapsed;
        tmrPause.Start();
    }
```

Here's the tmrPaused_Elapsed event handler:

```
    private void tmrPause_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                Del d = new Del(Prep4NextImage);
            }
            else
                Prep4NextImage();
        }
    }
```

And finally, the Prep4NextImage method:

```
    private void Prep4NextImage()
    {       
        tmrPause.Stop();
        glbblIsCorrectImage = false;
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is PictureBox)
                ctrl.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

All the above methods/event handlers are executed in the order they're listed above.

What should happen is that each of the 12 images should appear on the screen one by one with a 2-second pause between images. What's happening instead is that all 12 images appear on-screen all at once. Either tmrPause isn't running for the required 2 seconds between images or some code is written incorrectly or misplaced.

Comment: You keep adding handler after handler in your timer start-up. That accumulates.  Not sure why you wouldn't just use the WinForms timer instead.  Wouldn't your SlideShow method show everything at once?

Comment: Thanks for your replay LarsTech. I tried the WinForms timer, but the problem is the same. As for the repetitious addition of handlers, I'll try creating one in the form's constructor. Other than that, I'm still trying to generate a pause between images. Thread.Sleep() is out of the question because the user might press a key that won't do anything while the thread is asleep.

Comment: If you are going to use a timer, you can't use a loop.  Your SlideShow method is a loop showing all of the transitions, is it not?  Your timer code should do the increment to the next image.  Your timer is, what? Disposing all of your pictureBoxes?  BTW, I don't think that would work right since you are modifying a collection in a ForEach loop.  That's a no-no.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Lars. This is actually the first time I tried to get a timer and a for loop to work together. I'll try something else.